# Simple HiveQL query fails with vague SemanticException

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I'm working with an HDInsight cluster using Hive.  I've already gotten out the data I needed piecemeal, but I attempted this query along the way – it didn't work – and I'd like to understand why.

I've read the HiveQL spec, entered the query into HiveQL syntax checkers and as far as I can tell, this should work.

```
select yr, mon, day, hr, count(*)
from table
where yr = '2014' and mon in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06')
group by yr, mon, day, hr;
```

Fails with

```
...
FAILED: SemanticException MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query)
```

So why does it fail?  And/or is there a way to turn on warnings/increase error reporting to get more insight when failures are reported with vague exceptions like this?

Comment: Hive errors are remarkably uninformative.  My best guess is that a column name is wrong.

Comment: Well I'll take support that I'm not crazy, but col names aren't it. The same query with `mon = '05'` instead of `mon in...` works fine.

Comment: Is `mon` a number or a string?  You might just try `mon between '01' and '06'` or `mon in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Comment: how you resolve this error @conner.xyz is this column datatype error or what ?